# How to make a div blinking cursor? react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have my code below, and its normally working. But I want the *div-outputDisplay* has a blinking cursor just like a textarea, a controllable blinking cursor in which I can turn on or off. Is there any possibilities to do that?

---

```
<div id="outputDisplay">{inputedData}</div>

<SampleKeyboard>
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => setInputedData(inputedData + 'A')}>A<button>
        <button onClick={() => setInputedData(inputedData + 'B')}>B<button>
    </div>
</SampleKeyboard>
```

---

blinking cursor:

[image]

Comment: `contenteditable="true"` https://caniuse.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

You can put a span for blinking cursor at the end of the state. And put css animation on it, to look like it blinking.

Also state `blinkingHidden` will help you control the cursor blinking anytime you want it to display.

---

Here are the code:

```
<div>
    {inputedData}
    <span className={`${style.blinking} ${blinkingHidden ? style.hidden : ''}`}>|</span>
</div>
```

And css modular

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.cursorBlink{
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:30px; //follow the content font-size
    color:black;
    width:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    animation:blink 1s steps(5,start) infinite
}
@keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}
@-moz-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}
@-ms-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}
@-o-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}
```

> Note: It's a dirty solution but working best for your problem. You can scroll to other answer :)